# LoL API query for multiple titles from array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have an array:

```
Array ( [0] => Ahri [1] => Akali [2] => Alistar [3] => Amumu [4] => Anivia [5] =>  Annie [6] => Ashe [7] => Blitzcrank [8] => Brand [9] => Caitlyn [10] => Cassiopeia [11] => Cho'Gath [12] => Corki [13] => Dr. Mundo [14] => Evelynn [15] => Ezreal [16] => Fiddlesticks [17] => Fiora [18] => Fizz [19] => Galio [20] => Gangplank [21] => Garen [22] => Gragas [23] => Graves [24] => Hecarim [25] => Heimerdinger [26] => Irelia [27] => Janna [28] => Jarvan IV [29] => Jax [30] => Karma [31] => Karthus [32] => Kassadin [33] => Katarina [34] => Kayle [35] => Kennen [36] => Kog'Maw [37] => LeBlanc [38] => Lee Sin [39] => Leona [40] => Lulu [41] => Lux [42] => Malphite [43] => Malzahar [44] => Maokai [45] => Master Yi [46] => Miss Fortune [47] => Mordekaiser [48] => Morgana [49] => Nasus [50] => Nautilus [51] => Nidalee [52] => Nocturne [53] => Nunu [54] => Olaf [55] => Orianna [56] => Pantheon [57] => Poppy [58] => Rammus [59] => Renekton [60] => Riven [61] => Rumble [62] => Ryze [63] => Sejuani [64] => Shaco [65] => Shen [66] => Shyvana [67] => Singed [68] => Sion [69] => Sivir [70] => Skarner [71] => Sona [72] => Soraka [73] => Swain [74] => Talon [75] => Taric [76] => Teemo [77] => Tristana [78] => Trundle [79] => Tryndamere [80] => Twisted Fate [81] => Twitch [82] => Udyr [83] => Urgot [84] => Varus [85] => Vayne [86] => Veigar [87] => Viktor [88] => Vladimir [89] => Volibear [90] => Warwick [91] => Wukong [92] => Xerath [93] => Xin Zhao [94] => Yorick [95] => Ziggs [96] => Zilean [97] => Lee Sin [98] => Orianna [99] => Yorick [100] => Leona [101] => Riven [102] => Lulu [103] => Hecarim [104] => Varus [105] => Malphite [106] => Morgana [107] => Ryze [108] => Annie [109] => Cho'Gath [110] => Taric [111] => Jax [112] => Teemo [113] => Warwick [114] => Poppy [115] => Garen [116] => Anivia [117] => Blitzcrank [118] => Corki [119] => Karthus [120] => Twitch [121] => Irelia [122] => Miss Fortune [123] => Galio [124] => Swain [125] => Kennen [126] => Malzahar )
```

I need to use each of these values inside the following function:

```
$input=file_get_contents("http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=$value&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml");
```

Where the `$value` is a value from the array (eg. `Ahri`).

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** I get these values by doing:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_champions&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml');
preg_match_all('/{{ci\|([^}]*)}}/', $file, $matches);
```

*(Where `$matches` is the array mentioned above.)*

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can use the inbuilt way for the [LeagueOfLegends API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) and retrieve all values at the same time by separating each title with the `|` character. Like so:

```
$values = array("Ahri","Akali","Alistar");
$input  = "";

while($pack = array_splice($values,0,49)){
    $concatValues = implode("|",$values); // Will return "Ahri|Akali|Alistar";
    $url   = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=$concatValues&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml";
    $input .= file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Which for the first three elements of your code, would return the following, you can do it one by one, but the API etiquette suggests that you do the least number of requests to get the data you're after.

```
<api>
    <query>
    <pages>
        <page pageid="281432" ns="0" title="Ahri">
            <revisions>
                <rev xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Ahri the 9 Tails Fox]]</rev>
            </revisions>
        </page>
        <page pageid="5578" ns="0" title="Akali">
            <revisions>
                <rev xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Akali the Fist of Shadow]]</rev>
            </revisions>
        </page>
        <page pageid="2202" ns="0" title="Alistar">
            <revisions>
                <rev xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Alistar the Minotaur]]</rev>
            </revisions>
        </page>
        </pages>
    </query>
</api>
```

Note that the results are cached, so if you want to get the same data twice, make sure to use the same request and not alter the order of the elements, since a new order would result in a new url and the results being fetched again from their servers instead of serving the API cached version.

**Update**

Looking at the values in the array, I see some 'titles' that contains quotes and would therefor break the url. You should encode the url with `url encode` prior to using it.

Comment: I have updated my main post showing how I got the array. 
Is it possible to use your solution with my existing array instead of redefining it?

Comment: You're not redefining it, your concatenating it.  In my code, change `$values` with `$matches` or whatever and it should be what you're after.

Comment: `$concatValues = implode("|",$matches); // Will return "Ahri|Akali|Alistar";
$url   = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=$concatValues&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml";
$input = file_get_contents($url);
print $input;`
Returns nothing.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, my code is valid and tested. Check the value of the `$url` to see if there's something wrong there

Comment: I copy pasted your one exactly and just put in my array from before. 

Its still not working :(

Comment: Here is my full code : http://sdrv.ms/JzxrV3
Here is the loldb.txt file : http://sdrv.ms/JzxyQi

Comment: Can't you see the error yourself? `<query xml:space="preserve">
Too many values supplied for parameter 'titles': the limit is 50
</query>`

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I'm not that good at this yet. Thank you for your help and time, I really appreciate it :)
Also, is there any way to queue up this up so I can do 50 requests and then another 50 requests to get all my data?

Comment: Sure, check my update in a minute, I'll write it down for you

Comment: Note that it's `splice` and not `slice` in the while loop

Comment: I tried :
`$values = $matches;
$input  = "";

while($pack = array_splice($values,0,49)){
    $concatValues = implode("|",$values); // Will return "Ahri|Akali|Alistar";
    $url   = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=$concatValues&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml";
    $input .= file_get_contents($url);
 print $input;
}`
But it outputs nothing :/